# Find expected value of product of wiener process and stochastic integral

Tags: stochastic-analysis, means

Find expected value of $$Y_t = W_{1/4}\int_{0}^{1/2}\cos{t}\,dW_t$$

Firstly, I thought that $E[Y_t] = 0$. But then I realized that
$ W_{1/4}\int_{0}^{1/4}\cos{t}\,dW_t $ could be dependent.

---

We can represent $Y_t$ as the sum of two integrals:
$$Y_t = W_{1/4} \left ( \int_{0}^{1/4}\cos{t}\,dW_t + \int_{1/4}^{1/2}\cos{t}\,dW_t \right )$$
Then
$$ E[Y_t] = E \left [W_{1/4} \int_{0}^{1/4}\cos{t}\,dW_t\right ] + E \left [ W_{1/4}\int_{1/4}^{1/2}\cos{t}\,dW_t \right ] $$
Where second part is $0$

So
$$ E[Y_t] = E \left [W_{1/4} \int_{0}^{1/4}\cos{t}\,dW_t\right ] $$
We can represent $W_{1/4}$ as $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(W_{t_{i+1}} - W_{t_i})$

Also: $\int_{0}^{1/4}\cos{t}\,dW_t $ as $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\cos t_i (W_{t_{i+1}} - W_{t_i})$
$$ 
\begin{align*}
E[Y_t] &= E \left [ \sum_{i=1}^{n}(W_{t_{i+1}} - W_{t_i}) \sum_{i=1}^{n}\cos t_i (W_{t_{i+1}} - W_{t_i}) \right ] \\
 &= E \left [ \sum_{i=1}^{n}\cos t_i (W_{t_{i+1}} - W_{t_i})^2 \right ]
\end{align*}
$$
Is it correct?

Comment: Almost. The sum should be the limit of a Riemann-Stieltjes sum. Then you have in the limit $\int_0^{1/4}\cos t\,dt$ which you can evaluate.